# Zebra GK420d ZPL printer status in java via USB

Tags: java, usb, status, zebra-printers, zpl

How to query the recepit printer to get current status (ready/error/paper end)?
Is it provided with a virtual-COM interface for bi-directional communication?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zebra has an SDK (in Java) that handles Windows PC (as well as Android) USB communication.  It may or may not support your printer, but I encourage you to investigate even if your printer isn't explicitly listed: http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/link-os/link-os-sdk.html

Comment: I tried the PC demo... my printer is found by LinkOS but when I try to get status I get a com.zebra.sdk.comm.ConnectionException: Error writing to connection: ZDesigner GK420d

Comment: Seems it is not supported by LinkOS

Comment: Also, unfortunately USB communication is not supported on linux.